# Allow apk installation on all CPUs, with an ARM only lib in the app

Tags: android, architecture, android-ndk, arm

I'm building an Android app using some C++ features (through the NDK). These features are not mandatory (I have a slower fallback solution, not using the NDK). In order to keep the apk light, I'd like to build my ndk lib only for ARM, and use my fallback solution for other platforms.

Is it possible to do that? If so, how? By default, if I provide my lib only for ARM, users running an x86 (for instance) device won't be able to install the app.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious on similar situation once and handled it by placing empty files renaming it in proper .so format in the other cpu architectures and while loading library catching the exception.

```
try{
    System.loadLibrary("some_library");
} catch (Throwable e){
    //switch to fallback mode
}
```

You may also need catch exception while calling the native methods.

I am not sure whether 0 kB files works or not. But small file>0KB works. At least building different .so files by removing all the code should generate very small .so files which will surely work.

Comment: Nice idea, but there is a caveat: I'm not building an app but an SDK. Imagine an app using my SDK and the NDK, providing .so for all architectures. If I'm only providing armeabi-v7 and trying to run on an armv8 device, Android will see that some .so are provided for armv8 and will fail to load my armv7 .so files.

Comment: So don't put fake so file for armv8.Just don't distribute any so file for armv8 and android will try to use your so file of v7.

Comment: Nope, if the devs using my SDK provide .so files for armv8, Android will only look in the armv8 folder, even if my .so are not there

Comment: For that case, save .so file inside assets or raw directory and try to load library using absolute path of the .so file.

Comment: Not working either for now because I have one .so referencing other .so. When trying to load that 1st .so, Android seems to try to load the other .so in the usual folder (where they are not). Maybe I can bundle all these .so into one, I need to do some research on that.

Comment: OK. Good luck on your research and your SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I can't accept your answer as it's not working for me but I +1'd it, as it is relevant.

Comment: It's okay. Not a problem.